# Как убрать ограничение на входной файл?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Как в коде приведенном ниже снять ограничение на размер вводимого файла? По условию задачи файл может быть размером до 10 Гигабайт. Или хотя бы как преобразовать size к int?

```
ifstream::pos_type size;
char * memblock; //сюда уходят данные считывания
char * memblock1; //здесь играемся с массивом
char * sB;
int n= 0;
sB = new char [6];

ifstream inFile (chFiName1, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
ofstream outFile (chFiName2, ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);

size = inFile.tellg();
memblock = new char [size];
memblock1 = new char [size];
inFile.seekg (0, ios::beg);
inFile.read (memblock, size);
long int rlen = inFile.gcount(); //вот здесь ораничение
memcpy(memblock1,memblock,size);

for (int i=0; i<rlen; i++)
{
if ((memcmp ( memblock1, sB, 6 ))==0)
{MessageBox::Show("Работает");
outFile.write (memblock1, 6);
memmove(memblock1, memblock1 + 6, rlen -6);
} 
else
{ memmove(memblock1, memblock1 + 1, rlen -1);
}
}
```

Comment: Реально Вы не сможете работать в памяти с 10 гигабайтами.

Что на самом деле в задании?

Comment: Цитата из задания: "Размер обрабатываемого файла может быть до 10 Гбайт."

Comment: И зачем же вы его весь хотите прочитать в память?

Comment: @MartinSeptim, если Вы не можете складно на русском языке объяснить что **конкретно** требуется сделать (исходные данные, результат), то скорее всего Вам тут не помогут.

Подозреваю, что правильное решение не такое, как Вы придумали.

Comment: @avp: ТС вроде бы ищет заданный паттерн внутри файла. Для этого, разумеется, вполне достаточно читать файл небольшими порциями.

Comment: @VladD, похоже, что так. 

На самом деле и в 32-бит можно позиционироваться по большому файлу (см. SEEK_CUR в lseek()). 

Но, что-то не хочется додумывать условия задачи за ТС.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

10 гигабайт — это < 2^4Г = 2^4 * 2^30 = 2^34. Вам нужен 64-битный `std::streamsize`. Для этого компилируйтесь под [64-битный target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11zy8h28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Если у вас 32-битная машина, oops. Под 32-битный target `std::streamsize` определён как `int`, и имеет [32 бита](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую